# Open gridview inside template field of gridview

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0, gridview

I have image button in template field of gridview. I want to open another gridview below the row of which the plus button is clicked but my problem is that the inner gridview opens as a column of parent grid view and not opening below the selected row. I tried various design methods but still not working. I am using Jquery to open child gridview on image button click. Below is the design of my grid and code for Jquery.

```
<div class="gridContentholder">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdsamplestock" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="styleGrid" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdsamplestock_SelectedIndexChanged"
                OnRowDataBound="grdsamplestock_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="grdsamplestock_RowCreated">
          <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
          <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSampleStockMasterID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("SampleStockMasterID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DoctorName" DataField="DoctorName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Comments" DataField="Comments" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TotalSampleStockQuantity" DataField="TotalSampleStockQuantity" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SampleDate" DataField="SampleDate" SortExpression="SampleDate"
                        DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false" NullDisplayText="N/A" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href="javascript:expandcollapse('div<%# Eval("SampleStockMasterID") %>', 'one');">
                                <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("SampleStockMasterID") %>" alt="Click to show/hide Orders for Customer <%# Eval("SampleStockMasterID") %>"
                                    width="9px" border="0" src="../Images/plus.gif" />
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%--<asp:Panel ID="pnlInnerGrid" runat="server" >--%>
                            <tr style="display: none;" id="div<%# Eval("SampleStockMasterID") %>">
                                <td colspan="5">

                                    <asp:GridView ID="grdItems" CssClass="styleGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" runat="server"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" OnRowCreated="grdItems_RowCreated"
                                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" >
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reference No" DataField="ReferenceNo" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="ProductName" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Specification" HeaderText="Specification" SortExpression="Specification" />
                                            <%--  <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreKeeparID" HeaderText="StoreKeeparID" SortExpression="StoreKeeparID" />--%>
                                            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="StoreKeeper Name" SortExpression="Name" />--%>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="WarehouseName" HeaderText="Warehouse" SortExpression="WarehouseNmae" />
                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expiry Date" DataField="ExpiryDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}"
                                                HtmlEncode="false" />
                                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Lot No" DataField="LotNo" />
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="SampleStockTrsID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("SampleStockTrsID") %>' />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <%--   </asp:Panel>--%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
   </div>
```

//Code for Jquery.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //            var=$('div[id^="player_"]')

    });
    function expandcollapse(obj, row) {
        var div = document.getElementById(obj);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);
        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "";
            $(div).hide().show(1000);
            if (row == 'alt') {
                img.src = "../Images/minus.gif";
            }
            else {
                img.src = "../Images/minus.gif";
            }
            img.alt = "Close to view other Sample Transaction";
        }
        else {
            $(div).hide(1000, function () {
                div.style.display = "none";
            });
            if (row == 'alt') {
                img.src = "../Images/plus.gif";
            }
            else {
                img.src = "../Images/plus.gif";
            }
            img.alt = "Expand to show Available Stock";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Do you want something like this?   http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ux0AC.png

Comment: @Krishanu Dey..Somewhat like this....

Comment: Ok, Please give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I had used this in one of my previous projects. Giving the exect code sample from my project. Just modify it according to your need. feel free to ask questions.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns> 
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#C2D88B" Width="250px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                    //Draw your table here by placing a html table
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("item_id") %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                            <br />                                        
                            </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: This is not working in my case because I have few columns in my parent grid. Out of them, one column contains image button which when clicked, child grid should expand below the row of parent grid. But in your code, Parent grid does not have columns.